# How do I transfer equipment?

Tags: ragnarok-mobile

My character has a equipment (a bow) that my job (Thief) cannot equip. My sister plays as an Archer. How do I give the bow to my sister?

To add to this, my sister has a Dagger which I can use, so our plan was to swap.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trade option available yet for Ragnarok M: Eternal Love. The only way of transfering is from Exchange NPC.

Comment: Somebody explain why the -1 please. Is this answer wrong?